# ASP.Net, pass string list into Javascript dropdowlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Can you explain a little bit about how to  pass string list into Javascript dropdowlist?

Right now I already have a string list
List aaa= new List();

And I assigned values into it, say aaa[0]= 0, aaa[1][1]=1 and so on.

In my aspx page I have Javascripts which I need to build a dropdownlist, the values are from string list 'aaa'.

```
var a = JSON.parse('<% = this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.aaa) %>');          

        var populateSubjectItems = function ()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                return [{ value: a[i], text: a[i]}];
            }
        }
```

My code does not work.

Big thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function execution will stop as soon as you get to the first `return` statement.  Instead of putting the `return` inside of the for loop, you will want to create an array before the loop, populate inside of the loop, and return it after the loop.  For example:

```
var populateSubjectItems = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result.push({value: a[i], text: a[i]});
    }
    return result;
};
```

Of course you will also need to call this function for it to do anything, so I'm assuming you have some other code somewhere else that does this.